# all of my html files uses filename as title and shows nothing on the screen

Tags: html

I've tried atom, notepad++ and VScode but nothing works. When i run a html file it uses file name as a title instead of the one that i wrote and the body part is just a blank white space
it doesn't shows anything i wrote to body. I don't think this issue is because of the code because i used several codes.

[A simple code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3vrV.png)

[ss of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlhud.png)

Comment: Using the `file:///` protocol is notoriously fickle. You should probably run a local webserver using something like Apache so you have control over how the content is being served.

Comment: I did not understand anything

Comment: You are opening your file in a web browser by going to `file:///the/file/path/test.html`. That's very fickle and doesn't work well. You need to host a local server. When you connect to someone else's website (stackoverflow.com, for instance), you're not just poking files on their system. There's a program like Apache in the background on their computer that says "hey, Gryes just asked for this page, let's show them this information". You need that program running on your computer if you want to do web development. Then you'll connect to your site using something like `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Ok, i get it and thank you but none of my friends faced such a problem. 
They downloaded VSCode and just ran it. Do you have any idea why it's just me. (Also i've found an extension called live server and now i can run it with it)

Comment: I doubt it's a VSCode issue. It's probably a difference in web browsers or operating systems between you and your friends.